# make a object animated for part of animation, and rigid body for another part of it

Tags: animation, rigging, rigidbody

i'm trying to make  an animation, in which a robot arm picks up a box and drops it away. i've animated the box until the point of dropping, but i do not know how to make it turn into  a rigid body after that. i've three constraints, and they all turn off at frame 251 for rigid body.

[image: snapshot of part of my animation]

here is a snapshot of part of my animation

the clamp to constraint is switched off at frame 99

the copy location and copy rotation gets disabled at frame 251

I would like to start the rigid body sim after that

*P.S. i will include the blend file as soon as i figure out how to do so*

Comment: blend-exchange.com is the official way, pasteall.org/blend supports some larger files, and past that whatever your favorite cloud storage provider is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate your object with rigid body until one frame before the simulation should start.

At that frame keyframe animated (on):

[image]

one frame later keyframe animated (off):

[image]

example:

[image]

Comment: thanks, it worked